# How to run loop from 1 to 19 to generate output and print a plot in python

Tags: python, loops

I need to run the below code for ncomp=1 to 19 and print the graph of MSE vs Ncomp number. So far I have done the below code and generated one SME:

```
ncomp =19
pca=PCA(n_components=ncomp)
X_pca=pca.fit_transform(X)

TestModels(pd.DataFrame(X_pca),Y)
```

Output:
Linear Regression Mean Square error=  116599.01367380307

I need to plot the mean squared error as
a function of the number of components from 1 to 19.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the plotting, but a for-loop that iterates over the numbers 1 to 19 looks like this:

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    print(i) # replace this with your code
```